# sox and ffmpeg combine mp3 fails `Input files must have the same sample-rate`

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, sox

I am trying to combine mp3 files via sox using:

```
sox in.mp3 in2.mp3 out.mp3
```

and I get:

```
sox FAIL sox: Input files must have the same sample-rate
```

tried the `-m` option, but I guess this is default.

I also tried doing this via ffmpeg like so:

```
printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.mp3 > mylist.txt && ffmpeg -sn -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -acodec copy output.mp3
```

But the output file `output.mp3` is sort of screwed, it plays only the first song and nothing else :(

Is there an elegant solution to this?

Any help would be great..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to re-sample the affected files, which means re-encoding at least some of them.

For example, to resample to 44.1 kHz:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -ar 44100 out.mp3
```

Don't forget setting [an appropriate encoder and bitrate or VBR](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Answer (score 5):

You can use **sox** tool:

```
sox fileSource -r 48000 fileDestination
```

Or using **ffmpeg**:

```
ffmpeg -i fileSource -ar 48000 fileDestination
```

if you are using **NodeJs** you can use this function

```
 var child_process = require('child_process');

   function convertFileSampleRate(file, rate, destination, callback){
        // using sox:
        let command = 'sox' +
            ' ' + file +
            ' ' + '-r' +
            ' ' + rate +
            ' ' + destination;

        // or using ffmpeg:  ffmpeg -i file -ar 44100 destination

        child_process.exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error " + err);
                if (callback) {
                    callback(false);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (callback) {
                callback(true);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, thank you.

Comment: Removed the downvote, thanks for updating the post.